# Elasticsearch serving data for 2 apps

Tags: elasticsearch

I have 2 web applications where I am indexing data on elasticsearch in 2 different servers and currently using facetflow.io as an elasticsearch hosting service(I have 2 accounts on facetflow.io).

Now I am configuring an ubuntu server and I want both apps to point to the same ubuntu elasticsearch server and make it serve elasticsearch data for both of my apps python web apps.

What's the best approach:

- Is it possible and do I have to run multiple elasticsearch instances
  in the ubuntu server?
- Configuring the server, do I need multiple
  nodes?
- Authentication, do I use elasticsearch shield or is there any
  other option avaliable for free?